# In Perl app getting "Base class package _____ is empty" though paths appear correct

Tags: linux, perl

My directory tree:

```
/usr
   ->/home
       ->/highgatevps
           ->/apps
               ->Super.pm
               ->Validate.pm
               ->Common.pm
```

2nd line in module 'Rotators.pm':

```
use base qw(Super Validate Common);
```

Calling, or instance script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use lib '/usr/home/highgatevps/apps/';
use lib '/usr/home/highgatevps/apps/Slider';
use lib '/usr/home/highgatevps/cmspair/xm_admin';

use Rotators;

my $app = Rotators->new(
   PARAMS=>{
      app      => 'Slider',
   }
);
$app->run();
```

Rotator.pm

```
package Rotators;
use base qw(Super Validate Common);

use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Calc qw(Today);
use Data::Dumper;

$| = 1;

#--- SETUP Runmodes ------------------------------------------------------------

sub setup {
...
```

Validate.pm

```
package Validate; #used by forms built by Highsite public form builder

use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Valid;
use HTML::TagFilter;
use HTML::Entities;
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode;
use Encode::Guess;
...
```

Super.pm

```
package Super;

use warnings;
use strict;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); #set_message

use base 'CGI::Application';

#-------------------dependency issues here --------------
use CGI::Application::Plugin::FillInForm(qw/fill_form/);
...
```

Error shows the above `lib` in the `@INC`

```
Base class package "Validate" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: ... /usr/home/highgatevps/apps/
```

Oddly, the `Super.pm` does not throw the error (it did before I added the path in `use lib...`

Thoughts?

Comment: *"2nd line in module:"* Which module is this?

Comment: This is the module Rotators.pm that the instant script is calling

Comment: @breadwild *"This is the module Rotators.pm that the instant script is calling"*: Can you show that script also?

Comment: It would be nice if you could reduce it down to a minimal *runnable* example, then we could try to reproduce the error. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**
In working to create a "minimal reproducible example," I discovered another module of the same name deep in the @INC paths. And because they both contained different functions, the script was calling for a function not in module it was accessing first. By renaming one of the modules, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in that chain of modules there's likely a `use base` ([base.pm](https://perldoc.perl.org/base)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

package Foo {
    use base qw(Bar);
    }
```

This little snippet give this error:

```
Base class package "Bar" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains:...).
```

The `base` pragma is the old way we used to manipulate `@ISA`, the special variable Perl uses for the list of parent classes. The warning from `base` means it was not able to load that class.

The [parent](https://perldoc.perl.org/parent) pragma solves this problem (and others):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

package Foo {
    use parent qw(Bar);
    }
```

Now the program dies with a better error message that you've probably seen before:

```
Can't locate Bar.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Bar module) (@INC contains: ...) at ...
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `parent`. Are you saying that `parent` should replace `base` from now on?

Comment: parent was the next generation base and has been around for awhile. If you are using base now and not having a problem, I wouldn't rush to update everything. In most cases, you can simply replace `use base` with `use parent` and be okay. But, with all things, test that in a branch first.